# Unit tests if all subscriptions have been cleared in Angular/Redux

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx, subscription

I have an Angular application using ngrx and I am using the takeUntil approach with a subject to clear the subscriptions when the component is destroyed.

```
private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

this.store.select(actions.getTest)
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe((numberOfSelectedRoles: number) => {

    });

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next(true);
}
```

I decided to use this approach instead of keeping an array of subscriptions because it seems cleaner, but is there any way of writing unit tests in Jasmine to check if there are no open subscriptions for the component?

Answer (score 3):

We use takeWhile and a flag instead. That may be easier to test because you can just check the value of the flag.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Product } from '../product';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

/* NgRx */
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  componentActive = true;

  // Used to highlight the selected product in the list
  selectedProduct: Product | null;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromProduct.State>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Subscribe here because it does not use an async pipe
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromProduct.getCurrentProduct),
      takeWhile(() => this.componentActive)
    ).subscribe(
      currentProduct => this.selectedProduct = currentProduct
    );

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentActive = false;
  }

}
```